# How to use Python's Selenium to scrape search results?

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to scrape the results of Superhero battles created at the website https://www.superherodb.com/battle/create/

I've already scraped the list of all the superheroes and their stats from the website, now I want to enter their names and see who will win in the battle. I want to run a variation of each superhero vs everyone else. E.g Superman vs Thor, then Superman vs Spiderman, etc...

My list of characters and their info:

```
Characters = ["Superman", "Thor", "Spider-Man"]
Names = ["Kal-El", "Thor Odinson", "Peter Parker"]
Universes = ["Prime Earth", "Earth-616", "Earth-616"]
```

My ultimate goal is to make a for loop that runs through each character vs all other characters in the list, but the list is inaccessible to me from Selenium.

```
for i in range(len(Characters)):

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='C:\Webdriver\chromedriver.exe')
driver.get('https://www.superherodb.com/battle/create')

add = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='team1']/div/a") 
add.click()

text_area = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='s']") #team1 searchbar 
text_area.send_keys(Characters [i]) 


contents = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='quickselect_result']")

     if for elem in contents.find_elements_by_xpath('.//span[@class = "suffix level-1"]') == Names [i] and elem in browser.find_elements_by_xpath('.//span[@class = "suffix level-1"]') == Universes[i]:

#Here I want it to select that superhero in the team1 section. And replicate it to team2.
```

I want the for loop to also check for the specific version Character (e.g. Superman) with matching Name (Kal-El) and Universe (Prime Earth) and enter it in team1, also repeat this entry for team2 for the other Superhero and the page result will be for example: https://www.superherodb.com/superman-vs-thor/90-103/

I figured out this part. To figure out the result of the battle after entering both Superheroes in team1 and team2, I will scrape using this method:

```
wait=WebDriverWait(driver,10)
urls=['https://www.superherodb.com/superman-vs-thor/90-103/']
names=['Superman_vs_Thor']
complete_list={}
for indx,url in enumerate(urls):
    driver.get(url)
    battles=[]
    try:
        win=wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='battle-team-result win']"))).text
        battles.append(win)
    except:
        pass
    try:
        draw=wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='battle-team-result draw']"))).text
        battles.append(draw)
    except:
        pass
    try:
        loss=wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='battle-team-result lose']"))).text
        battles.append(loss)
    except:
        pass
    complete_list[names[indx]]= battles

print(complete_list)
```

Which gives me:

```
{'Superman_vs_Thor': ['912 wins (52%)', '35 (2%)', '806 wins (46%)']}
```

But I am stuck in the part of selecting the specific version of the character with their names and universes in both team1 and team2 and then creating the battle and viewing the battle's page to scrape it for the results because the list is not appearing in my code.

[Menu for selecting Superhero](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ChamM.png)

I am stuck here, after entering the Superhero, how do I access the list and select the superhero with his right name and universe.

Comment: I find this project interesting! So  you have a list of two teams with characters and make them battle all against each other, and each time scrape the results am I right?

Comment: Yes, thank you. Precisely that's what I want.

Comment: And at whitch stade are you stuck? entering characters, or scraping the results

Comment: I can enter the characters with ```text_area.send_keys(Characters [i]) ```, but when I enter the Character, I have to select the specific Character from the list with the xpath: ("//*[@id='quickselect_result']"), but I cannot access the list and it's elements as it is hidden. Also to select the right version of the character, I need to make sure that it also has the right universe and name because there are many versions of the same character

Comment: I added a picture to my question to show you where I am stuck exactly

Comment: I do get the xpath of the character dropdown list and diferent universes, you can use the select button when inspecting the webpage and select the character in the dropdown list it will bring you to the corresponding html line

Comment: Yes buy when I select the list's xpath with ```driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='quickselect_result']")``` it doesn't seem to work

Comment: I get this error with select: ```Select only works on <select> elements, not on <ul>```

Comment: I am trying to write a working code, I will give it to you once ready

Comment: Ok great, God bless you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the code that selects character, you have to add a loop, character rotation and print the results

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from time import sleep


#Characters = ["Superman", "Thor", "Spider-Man"]
#options: (superman vs thor) (superman vs spider man) (spider man vs thor)

char_1 = 'superman'
char_2 = 'spider'

driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:/chromedriver.exe')
driver.get('https://www.superherodb.com/battle/create')
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 5)

wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="qc-cmp2-ui"]/div[2]/div/button[3]'))).click()
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, 300)")

#sleep(999)


def team1():
    wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="team1"]/div/a'))).click() # add member team 1
    wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="f_pub"]'))).click() # universe dropdown list team 1
    wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="f_pub"]/option[2]'))).click() # dc comics team 1
    wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.NAME, 'quickselect'))).send_keys(char_1) # write character name team 1

    wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="quickselect_result"]/li[2]'))).click() # superman kal el team 1
    wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="add_member"]/div/div[3]/a'))).click() # done button team 1
    return


def team2():
    wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="team2"]/div/a'))).click() # add member team 2
    wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="f_pub"]'))).click() # universe dropdown list team 2
    wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="f_pub"]/option[3]'))).click() # marvel team 2
    wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="s"]'))).clear() # clear character dropdown list team 2
    wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.NAME, 'quickselect'))).send_keys(char_2) # write character name team 2
    sleep(1)
    wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="quickselect_result"]/li[1]'))).click() # spiderman peter parker team 2
    wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="add_member"]/div/div[3]/a'))).click() # done button team 2
    return

def battle_result():
    wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.NAME, 'battle_start'))).click()
    #your turn


team1()
team2()
battle_result()
```

Comment: I seem to be getting ```TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)``` error. Also in your code you select the elements of the list manually if they are in the right universe and they have the right name (I have the full list of 15,000 superheroes), so there are many variations of the same hero. While inspecting the list elements, the value for their name is ```find_elements_by_xpath('.//span[@class = "suffix level-1"]')``` and 
 universe is ```find_elements_by_xpath('.//span[@class = "suffix level-2"]')```. Hence why I made the if statement to check the respective name and universe of hero

Comment: I made three lists (Superhero, Name and Universe), so I want to select automatically the Superhero and his respective Name and Universe, since I could have the same superhero but various variations of him from different Universes for example. So how can I check the Superman from the list li[3] has suffix level-1 == "other name" and suffix level-2 == "other universe" for example?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71499970/python-selenium-only-print-if-class-has-a-certain-value-only-print-certain-e Look a this question

Comment: I can't try anything since I'm getting this error ```TimeoutException: Message: 
Stacktrace:
Backtrace:```  But I understand the answer to the question that you gave me, I will try it once I figure out a way out of this error

Comment: try setting the wait = time higher, it controls the timeout

Comment: I set the wait to 30, still nothing

Comment: then find which element raises the TimeoutExeption and check if it is the right xpath, if you dont get it, DM me the full code, I will take a look at it. [telegram](https://t.me/xtekky)

Comment: God you're a lifesaver. You have no idea how much I appreciate this. OK I found the wrong xpath and removed it and the code works, will try it fully and get back to you if I encounter any error